# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

After one month I decided to work on my app again. I open it and run it and I got this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`. I remember that it worked fine, maybe there was a beautifulsoup update or the website (real estate) changed something? But no, the code is the same.

Here's the line that causes trouble according to the compiler:

```
propertyQuantity = soup.find("h1", {"class":"list-result-title"}).find("b", recursive = False).text
```

I can post the whole code if necessary. Do you notice something wrong with that line?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your entire code necessary to reproduce the error as a [mcve]. Without knowing what the document looks like, it's impossible to tell you why `.find()` is returning empty handed. Also, an `AttributeError` is a runtime exception which is raised by the interpreter, not the compiler. If you're scraping a live website, there's plenty of reason to think the DOM changed during the past month.

Comment: This means it's not finding the `h1` element.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I would upvote you if I had the ability. I printed the scraped websites code as a whole instead of just the h1 and it returns the source code of a captcha validation. Apparently they block you if you send a couple of requests :/

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find()` returns `None` if it can't find the element you specify. You need to check for this before trying to invoke other methods on the result. So split it up into two statements:

```
h1 = soup.find("h1", {"class":"list-result-title"})
if h1:
    property = find("b", recursive = False)
    if property:
        propertyQuantity = property.text
    else:
        // report problem finding `b`
else:
    // report problem finding h1
```